# selecting records from hive table where there are duplicates with a given criteria

Tags: hadoop, select, hive, duplicates

[image]

Table 1 has duplicate entries in column A with same frequency values. I need to select one random record out of those  .If the duplicate entry contain 'unknown' as a column B value ( like in record "d") select one from other rows . I need a select statement which satisfy the above . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

These conditions can be prioritized using a `case` expression in `order by` with a function like `row_number`.

```
select A,B,frequency,timekey
from (select t.*
            ,row_number() over(partition by A order by cast((B = 'unknown') as int), B) as rnum
      from tbl t
     ) t 
where rnum = 1
```

Here for each group of A rows, we prioritize rows other than `B = 'unknown'` first, and then in the order of `B` values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number` analytic function. If you want to select not `unknown` record first, then use the query below:

```
select  A, B, Frequency, timekey
from
(select 
       A, B, Frequency, timekey,
       row_number() over(partition by A,Frequency order by case when B='unknown' then 1 else 0 end) rn
)s where rn=1
```

And if you want to select `unknown` if they exist, use this `row_number` in the query above:

```
row_number() over(partition by A,Frequency order by case when B='unknown' then 0 else 1 end) rn
```